# CGAffineTransformRotate behaviour inconsistent between view and view controller

Tags: ios, rotation, cgaffinetransform

I am trying to replicate Music.app's volume thumb reflections. I created a [demo project](http://cl.ly/2u361m041g12)
to fine-tune the maths.

At first, I was animating the views in the controller to keep it simple. After I had done that, I decided to create a custom `ReflectedKnobView` so that I could use it in other projects. I copied the relevant code from the controller to the view.

Even though I copied my code exactly as it was in the controller (making relevant modifications) but when I run the app, the view differs in behaviour from the controller.

In the `ReflectedKnobView`, the `CGAffineTransformRotate()` skews and morphs the views in unpredictable ways.

Code I copied:

```
- (void)updateValues
{    
CMRotationRate data = self.mManager.gyroData.rotationRate;

self.xLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", RadiansToDegrees(data.x)];
self.yLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", RadiansToDegrees(data.y)];
self.zLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",RadiansToDegrees(data.z)];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1/20 animations:^{
    self.level3Left.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.level3Left.transform, ((data.y / 240) + (data.x / 200)));
    self.level3Right.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.level3Right.transform, ((-1 * data.y) / 240) + (data.x / 200));
}];
}
```

The `level3<Right/Left>` are `UIImageView`s.

I suspect that `CGAffineTransformRotate()` behaves differently because I am calling it in a view in one case and a controller in another.

Please download the [demo project](http://cl.ly/2u361m041g12) and run it on a device if you don't get what I am saying here.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a similar answer on another question  [How do I calculate the affine translation parameters when rotating a view in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606179/how-do-i-calculate-the-affine-translation-parameters-when-rotating-a-view-in-ios)

Here is a rehash of that:

You need to be careful about two things on your rotation-- your anchor point (the point about which the rotation occurs) and the dimensions of the view or viewController.

original view:

[image]

If your anchor point is in the corner, it rotates like this:

[image]

If your anchor point is in the middle, it rotates like this:

[image]

If you have a square layer, view, or view controller, it tends to rotate nicely.  A rectangular view will appear to be doing some weird stuff when rotating, but you can adjust for it, if you know the size differences.

Comment: Did you download the demo project? I have exactly the same code at two places, but they rotate the views in different ways. And I did not change the anchor point, so it defaults to the centre.